# Laravel check an array of object which contain in another array

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to get check my array of the object have title and id. I want to get all the array of objects where id exists in the existing array.

I tried using array_diff or array_intersect but error stating that it is supposed to be an array.

```
    if (!empty(session('selected_movies'))) {
        $current_movies = array_intersect($allMovies, session('selected_movies'));
    }
```

**The array of objects data**

```
    [
        {
            "id":"05595dd2-2f13-11ea-9e3f-42010a940008",
            "title":"Harry Potter"
        },
        {
            "id":"247d20cd-2f13-11ea-9e3f-42010a940008",
            "title":"Tom and Jerry"
        }
    ]
```

**Existing array data**

```
    ["247d20cd-2f13-11ea-9e3f-42010a940008", "51141418-4fb1-11ea-a428-7a79190f5c7d"]
```

Comment: why not just do a loop?

Comment: you meant do a foreach loop and check whether this id exist in that array?

Comment: yapp precisly that

Comment: ok but it brings to another problem how do I push an object to a new array? because when i push it become an array of array

Comment: updated my answer with alternative to push or to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a simple foreach and just unset if its missing desired id

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$array = json_decode('[
        {
            "id":"05595dd2-2f13-11ea-9e3f-42010a940008",
            "title":"Harry Potter"
        },
        {
            "id":"247d20cd-2f13-11ea-9e3f-42010a940008",
            "title":"Tom and Jerry"
        }
    ]');
     $check = ["247d20cd-2f13-11ea-9e3f-42010a940008", "51141418-4fb1-11ea-a428-7a79190f5c7d"];
   foreach($array as $index => $current){
       if(!in_array($current->id,$check)) unset($array[$index]);
   }
   print_r($array);
```

alternativly if you want to create a new array

```
         $mah = [];
 foreach($array as $index => $current){
       if(in_array($current->id,$check)) array_push($mah,$current);
   }
   print_r($mah);
```